# why could I not transfer by using msg.sender instead of passing address as an argument to the function?

Tags: solidity

The function withdraw() is not working, it can not transfer. But the function withdraw2() is working. What's wrong with my code?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract SupportPay4 {

    function() public payable {

    }

    function deposit() public payable {

    }

    function withdraw() public {
        msg.sender.transfer(getBalance());
    }

    function withdraw2(address addr) public {
        addr.transfer(getBalance());
    }

    function getBalance() public constant returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure you deposited ether again after calling Withdraw2?

Comment: yes,  I deposited  0.3 ether. I could withdraw all ether by function withdraw2(). But it's not working with function withdraw().

Comment: Yes, but did you deposit it again after withdrawing it the first time? I can withdraw from both.

Comment: I deployed the contract by the last version Ethereum Wallet. Is it the matter?

Comment: No, shouldn't make a different.

Comment: there no function withdraw2() first time. I added it for test.

Comment: I connected to Rinkeby (Test network)

Comment: It works fine for me in remix. There is likely something wrong in the way you are testing.

Comment: It got me crazy

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ***v0.8*** you need to change this to

`payable(msg.sender).transfer(address(this).balance);`

Hope this helps

Comment: Yeah I'm doing the Solidity, Blockchain, and Smart Contract Course and he's working with **v0.6** and the casting that you did solved it, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract SupportPay4 {

    function() public payable {

    }

    function deposit() public payable {

    }

    function withdraw() public {
        msg.sender.transfer(getBalance());
    }

    function withdraw2() public {
        msg.sender.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }

    function getBalance() public constant returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried, but still not working.

Comment: The contract works in Remix. You might want to test it there to see for yourself, then turn your attention to the client side, which may not be interacting with the contract properly.